# How to connect via adb to a (Remote Session) Android Device on AWS Device Farm

Tags: aws-device-farm

Can I connect to Android device during a remote session via adb?

I would need to connect to the Android device via adb( using tcpip mode) but I presume, I can't connect to a specific device via a public IP(?) so how can I connect from a ubuntu-server ec2 instance or a local machine to a device farm Android device during a remote session?

During the remote access session, the device has private ip, offcourse (e.g. 192.168.1.10).
Would using a VPC help in this regard?

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm responding to [this question in the AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=260524&tstart=0) since you've posted in both places.

Comment: @RohanDeshpande
I have marked your answer as correct on AWS Forum. If you can post the statement as an answer here as well, I would be happy to mark that as an answer here also. Thanks anyways for the help.:)

Comment: Dead link. Any actual information on that topic?

Comment: @stoefln: [new link](https://repost.aws/questions/QUitFvIMf_TzO7R-XZMDEb3w/how-to-connect-via-adb-to-a-remote-session-android-device-on-aws-device-farm) in repost.aws